# What to do when you can't press 3 keys at the same time with a laptop?

Tags: keyboard

I bought this new laptop and when I played some of my favorite games, it didn't let me use 3 keys at the same time. What do I do? Buying a new laptop isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Sounds like a game issue rather than laptop issue, as every device should support at least 3 keys for `CTRL + ALT + DEL`

Comment: Can you clarify what key combinations you are trying to use? And it might help to clarify which games you are playing too

Comment: This is known as a "key rollover" issue. Get a real gaming keyboard, or a classic IBM Model M! You can have my Model M when you pry it from my cold, dead hands!

Comment: Does the game give you the option of creating macros?  Or perhaps remapping keys to different parts of the keyboard (reading something about keys close together being on the "same circuit" in the duplicate)?  Granted this would be a game-specific solution that may not be doable in all games.  A programmable controller or gaming mouse might also be an option along these lines

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've had a problem like this before, and which keys cap out vary on how the keyboard groups its keys.  Modifiers like Ctrl/Alt/Delete/Shift tend to get their own signal lines since you'd never want to drop them, but to someone who is only typing, hitting 3 different letters at the same time is probably not meaningful input.